# Structures of files in java

Tags: java

Hello I am new in Java so I would like some guidelines on how to organize files of a project in java. Currently I am building an app with GUI so I want two files one that relates to the GUI and another file that relates to any functions that are called from the first. Right now I've named the second file Utilities.java and looks like this:

```
package Directory;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;


public class Utilities {

    public class FileCopy{
        private File  Source;
        private File Destination;
        private long totalBytes=0L;

        FileCopy(File source,File destination){
            Source=source;
            Destination=destination;
            retrieveTotalBytes(source);
        }

        File getSource(){return Source;}
        File getDestination(){return Destination;}
        Long gettotalBytes(){return totalBytes;}

        private void retrieveTotalBytes(File sourceFile)
        {
                if(sourceFile.isDirectory()==false){
                    totalBytes = sourceFile.length();
                }
                else{
                    File[] files = sourceFile.listFiles();
                    for(File file : files)
                    {
                        if(file.isDirectory()) retrieveTotalBytes(file);
                        else totalBytes += file.length();
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("Done retrieving");
         }  
    }


    public class Copy extends SwingWorker<Void,Integer>
    {

      File src,dest;
      InputStream in;
      OutputStream out;
      JProgressBar progressBar;
      JProgressBar all;
      JTextArea txt;
      public int progress;
      //private int all_progress;
      private long totalBytes = 0L;
      private long copiedBytes = 0L;
      boolean keepStructure=false;
      boolean delete=false;

          public Copy(File source,File dst,JProgressBar br,JTextArea text,boolean keep,boolean delete)
          {
             src=source;
             dest=dst;
             progressBar=br;
             txt=text;
             progressBar.setValue(0);
             progressBar.setVisible(true);
             txt.setText("Copying " + src.getName());
             keepStructure=keep;
             this.delete=delete;
          }

            @Override
            public Void doInBackground() throws Exception
            {
                txt.setText(src.getName());
                //retrieveTotalBytes(src);
                copyFiles(src, dest);

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void process(java.util.List<Integer> chunks)
            {
                for(int i : chunks)
                {
                    progressBar.setValue(i);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void done()
            {
                setProgress(100);
            }


            public String GetParent(String input){
                short pos=(short) input.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
                return input.substring(0, pos);
            }

            private void copyFiles(File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws IOException
            {
                if(sourceFile.isDirectory())
                {
                    if(!targetFile.exists()) targetFile.mkdirs();

                    String[] filePaths = sourceFile.list();

                    for(String filePath : filePaths)
                    {
                        File destFile;
                        File srcFile = new File(sourceFile, filePath);

                        if(keepStructure==true)
                            destFile= new File(targetFile, filePath);
                        else{
                            String filepath2=GetParent(dest.toString())+File.separatorChar+srcFile.getName();
                            destFile=new File(filepath2);
                        }

                        System.out.print("\n\n name="+destFile.toString()+"\n");
                        System.out.print("dest to string =" +GetParent(dest.toString()) + "  srcFile.getName()="+srcFile.getName()+"\n" );

                        copyFiles(srcFile, destFile);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile));

                    long fileBytes = sourceFile.length();
                    long soFar = 0L;

                    int theByte;

                    while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1)
                    {
                        bos.write(theByte);

                        setProgress((int) (copiedBytes++ * 100 / totalBytes));
                        publish((int) (soFar++ * 100 / fileBytes));
                    }

                    bis.close();
                    bos.close();
                    if(delete==true)
                        sourceFile.delete();
                    publish(100);
                    txt.setText("Copying " + src.getName() + "complete");
                  }
            } 
       }
}
```

Question 1:
Notice that in that file the I have two subclasses {FileCopy,Copy} that are completely different. Is that a good way to organize the code or should a move each class on each own file?

Question 2:
Also, in my main i try to create and object from each class but I do something wrong. I've added the import of the file but when I try to create an object e.g.

```
Copy worker = new Copy(source,dest,progressBar,textArea, keep_Structure,false);
```

I receive this error:

> No enclosing instance of type Utilities is accessible. Must qualify
>   the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Utilities (e.g.
>   x.new A() where x is an instance of Utilities).

Comment: Put it all in seperate .java files and propably your problems are gone. When you get further with Java, you will understand the details about inner (non-static) classes.

Comment: And right now at the beginning, you should follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: @PeterMmm Can you provide me with any good link about naming conventions? Thx in advance!

Comment: Here's a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) to wikipedia for the Java naming conventions. I'm still trying to get some offcial conventions from Oracle's website but can't find it yet.

Comment: Important naming conventions: packages names are completely lowercase (`package directory`), field names and method names start with lowercase but capitalize every next word: `getTotalBytes`, `private File destination;`. (and underscores are not used to separate words) And class names start with a capital and capitalize every next word.

Comment: You can leave both files in the Utilities container. That is ok. Your problem is that nested classes need a reference to the instance of Unitilty. Since you do not want that, mark them `static`, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Yes, this will work too. Though I don't feel like it is an appropritate way to do things, in particular when unfamiliar with the language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Java you should moslty (at least while you are still learning the basics) keep each class in its own file.**

You have 3 (and not 2) classes in your file : `Utilities`, `FileCopy` and `Copy`, with the later two being inner classes of `Utilities` (the `Utilities` class does nothing on its own). This is why you can't instanciate `Copy` without first instantiating `Utilities`.

I think you should have a package named `utilities`, containing two files : `FileCopy.java` and `Copy.java` each containing their own class. If you want a way to differentiate between parts of your application, this is a good way to start : have a package containing all gui-related classes and another one for the rest of the application.

This should solve your error.

The official tutorials on nested classes : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html